# Memory Leak, thought it was images, Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have a memory leak on my app. I thought it was the images, however, I ran the app with no XML and nothing but the main activity, which is now empty. The issue is that it still crashes.

I am thinking perhaps the images get loaded on the app anyway, even though they are not in any XML and that is why I get a memory overflow.

Does that make sense?

Any advice will help!

Thanks!

```
Process: com.android.launcher3, PID: 2176
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 125440012 byte allocation with 8214474 free bytes and 84MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:849)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.pm.LauncherActivityInfo.getIcon(LauncherActivityInfo.java:111)
at com.android.launcher3.compat.LauncherActivityInfoCompatVL.getIcon(LauncherActivityInfoCompatVL.java:48)
at com.android.launcher3.IconProvider.getIcon(IconProvider.java:47)
at com.android.launcher3.IconCache.updateCacheAndGetContentValues(IconCache.java:391)
at com.android.launcher3.IconCache.addIconToDBAndMemCache(IconCache.java:360)
at com.android.launcher3.IconCache.updateIconsForPkg(IconCache.java:226)
at com.android.launcher3.LauncherModel$PackageUpdatedTask.run(LauncherModel.java:3049)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Think of any unstopped loop or something like that. also, sharing your code may help answering.

Comment: try rebuilding the project and restarting your android studio, and share your code.

Comment: @FlyingNades I created an entirely new emulator. So its essentially a brand new phone. There is not code to share because I commented out everything besides the oncreate method, and that is empty. It is literally an empty app. That is why I am so confused. Not only that but it crashes and says system ui has crashed and then launcher 3 has crashed and then there is a loop between the two of them going back and forth and I cant get out of that look unless I restart the VM

Comment: @makkhaygurung^^

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I had the original drawables as a larger size in the app as well as the drawable-xxx. My hunch was that it was loading the original ones and not the xxx ones so then it was too large for the phone.